# "For the best part of a generation" - meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could you help me in understanding the exact meaning of a phrase "for the best part of a generation".
For example:

> **For the best part of a generation**--the welfare state generation of 1945-79--this interpretation of Britain's past carried almost
>   everything before it.

Source: (c) David Cannadine "The Rise and Fall of Class in Britain", http://www.nytimes.com/books/first/c/cannadine-class.html

Does it mean "for almost everyone" from this generation?
I come across with this phrase in many other papers and sources. Can it be used in direct(?) meaning in describing most notable representatives of a generation of scientists (like "for the best part of a generation, most scientists tend to write about this problem...")?

Answer (score 3):

**The best part** means *the biggest part* or *the most large part*.

A generation is a time period, usually about 20 years. It means the average amount of time it takes from birth to giving birth.

It also means *all of the people born and living at about the same time, regarded collectively,*  **and** *A group of individuals living at the same time, regarded as having common cultural or social characteristics and attitudes.*

> For the best part of a generation--the welfare state generation of 1945-79--

means

> Most of the time between 1945-79, when all of the people born at about the same time, regarded collectively lived, ...

Comment: I like this answer until the paraphrase; that wording seems a bit clunky or confusing to me.

Comment: That's because I substituted the **definitions** of **for the most part** and the proper choice of meanings for **generation**. It was meant as an explanation, not a finished piece of writing.

Comment: I noticed the substitution, but even after I read it three or four times, I still found it very hard to follow. My comment wasn't meant as a criticism, but I wanted to assure any others who might be reading this answer that, if they were having trouble making heads or tails of that last part, they weren't alone. I would have liked to offer a different suggestion, but I'm having trouble coming up with anything better, which is why I upvoted the O.P.'s question. I can sense the meaning of the phrase in question, but putting it into words is elusive. This is a tough nut to crack.

Answer (score 2):

Probably means "for most of a generation," meaning most of that period of time. "The best part" / "most" probably does not refer to a generation of people, but uses "generation" as a loosely defined period of time.  See [the third definition of "generation."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/generation) Confusing, ain't it!

Answer (score -1):

This is usually said to refer to (larger) periods inside periods of time.

> "For the best part of a generation"
>
> "For the best part of the decade"
>
> "For the best part of 1998"

A generation is usually a period of time that comprises 60 years.